# Preferred way Of getting Client name From Terminal Server Session

Tags: .net, terminal-services

I need to get the underlying client PC name from a user's terminal server session.

I know it lives in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Volatile Environment\CLIENTNAME` but is there another (preferably native .net) method of getting it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I didn't see a managed API for this.  The only API-based ways I could see for getting at this information would be through WMI or the native Terminal Services API in Windows.

Here is an example that returns the client name using the `WTSQuerySessionInformation` API:

```
namespace com.stackoverflow
{
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(GetTerminalServicesClientName());
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the name of the client system.
        /// </summary>
        internal static string GetTerminalServicesClientName()
        {
            IntPtr buffer = IntPtr.Zero;

            string clientName = null;
            int bytesReturned;

            bool success = NativeMethods.WTSQuerySessionInformation(
                NativeMethods.WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE,
                NativeMethods.WTS_CURRENT_SESSION,
                NativeMethods.WTS_INFO_CLASS.WTSClientName,
                out buffer,
                out bytesReturned);

            if (success)
            {
                clientName = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(
                    buffer,
                    bytesReturned / 2 /* Because the DllImport uses CharSet.Unicode */
                    );
                NativeMethods.WTSFreeMemory(buffer);
            }

            return clientName;
        }
    }

    public static class NativeMethods
    {
        public static readonly IntPtr WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE = IntPtr.Zero;
        public const int WTS_CURRENT_SESSION = -1;

        public enum WTS_INFO_CLASS
        {
            WTSClientName = 10
        }

        [DllImport("Wtsapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern bool WTSQuerySessionInformation(
            IntPtr hServer,
            Int32 sessionId,
            WTS_INFO_CLASS wtsInfoClass,
            out IntPtr ppBuffer,
            out Int32 pBytesReturned);

        /// <summary>
        /// The WTSFreeMemory function frees memory allocated by a Terminal
        /// Services function.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="memory">Pointer to the memory to free.</param>
        [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = false)]
        public static extern void WTSFreeMemory(IntPtr memory);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! You are a genious!!! And thanks for giving such a detailed explanation and adding code.

Comment: long time ago, but do you know why `WTS_INFO_CLASS.WTSUserName` return the local user and not the remote session user?

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completing these answers, there is a C# project hosted on the [Citrix Developer Network](http://community.citrix.com/) website that provide code to list sessions and their IP addresses on an RDP server:

[How to get client IP address and client hostname using Terminal Services API](http://community.citrix.com/display/xa/How+to+get+client+IP+address+and+client+hostname+using+Terminal+Services+API)