# How to restrict user for using application which is on Server?

Tags: c#, wpf, client-server, setup-project, rdp

I have developed wpf application and my application is ready for installation.
now i want to install setup in company which contain one server and more then 10 client.
Clients do not have their own CPUs as clients uses  server memory. Clients working with server using Remote desktop Connection(RDP) or By Anyway.

Case 1:

Now i want to install my software in server PC. But want give access of my software to 5 users(Clients) of server only.

For Example...
[image]

Red Line indicates Allow users to Access My software using  RDP or anyWay.

Case  2:

Also i want is that As Image says Client 2 don't have permission to access to my software so from anywhere Client 2 should not access my software.
Say for example if once user 5 or client 5 access My Software from one Machine on which he/she login usually, then after Client 5 can access my software from that machine only.
he/She can't not access it from Client 2 Machine using its own userName and Password.

As want to set permission by Each User PC..
So Should i need to to change in my application or in setup Project or i need to set some setting i my Client Server..

What should i do?

Answer (score 1):

Get the username of who is logged in to Windows and compare that to a list of users who are allowed to use your application.

Comment: as per u i need to Create users from application and then compare with database. If so then many uers can access my software using same username and password which is not allow.Can i get any Uniqe Id for each user?

Comment: I did not say "create user" nor "database". You can implement it any way you like, I'm just drawing the outline here as you didn't provide any information on how authentication works in your  environment. I assume it is an Active Directory-controlled environment, so you can check which user is **logged in to Windows**. If it (also) depends on client machine and not on logged in user, then (also) check the machine name.

Comment: What if i don't want to display even desktop icon on Restricted User?

Comment: Like I said, you don't provide any information on how the server works. Is it Citrix, then you can create packages that are only rolled out to certain users (or groups) and so on. Based on the information you currently provided, very little useful can be said.

Comment: As i want Scenario - How to Processed to my application from this que, how should i can i judge how server works..I am at position to find a way for my application that satisfy my requiements..As i want answer from you People what should i do?

Comment: Ask the IT department of your client how applications are installed on the server and if they have means to install applications for certain users only. If you cannot do or understand this, then you will need to  alter your program to look up which user is trying to run it and make a decision whether they are allowed to. If your clients access one installation on the server through remote desktop, you need to [get the client name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301079/preferred-way-of-getting-client-name-from-terminal-server-session).

Comment: My Server is Windows Server 2003. And I will prefer the solution which authorises Client Machines rather than Domain/Network Users. So what happens if two computer have same computer names ? Or if the computer name changes after PC formatting. We also need to minimize after sales support work.

Comment: You cannot have two computers with the same name on a network. If the computer name changes, you will have to change the list of computer names that are allowed to use your application.